# We are pleased to note

Tags: grammar

For college admission letters, I observed that "We are pleased to inform you...." rather than "We were pleased to inform you..."

Why is it so?

Comment: If they were once pleased, but are no longer pleased, then they could say "we were pleased".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"we were pleased " past continuous. 
Action starts in the past and finishes in the recent past

"we are pleased " present continuous. 
Action starts in the past and still yet to finish pleasant feeling still continuous